# Getting "Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'payment_id' cannot be null" using Doctrine & Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've been stuck for a couple of days dealing with this issue. I've been reviewing other StackOverflow questions and different forums but I couldn't get this to work, so that's the reason of this question.

I'm developing a system that contains payments, so I've created a "Payment" class as follow:

```
/**
 * Payment
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PaymentRepository")
 */
 class Payment
 {

   /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @JMS\Groups({"public"})
     * @JMS\Type("integer")
     */
     protected $id;

   /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PaymentLine", mappedBy="payment", cascade={"persist",    "remove"})
     * @Assert\Valid()
     * @JMS\Groups({"public","create"})
     * @JMS\Type("ArrayCollection<JensenTech\PaymentBundle\Entity\PaymentLine>")
     */
     protected $paymentLines;

     /**
       * @var string
       *
       * @ORM\Column(name="total_net", type="decimal", precision=5, scale=2)
       * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Invalid Net Amount")
       * @JMS\Groups({"public","create"})
       */
       protected $totalNet;

     /**
       * @var string
       * @ORM\Column(name="total_vat", type="decimal", precision=5, scale=2)
       * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Invalid VAT Amount")
       * @JMS\Groups({"public","create"})
       */
       protected $totalVat;

      /**
        * @var string
        * @ORM\Column(name="total_gross", type="decimal", precision=5, scale=2)
        * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Invalid Gross Amount")
        * @JMS\Groups({"public","create"})
        */
        protected $totalGross;

}
```

And I've created another class called PaymentLine to store details about each payment line:

```
/**
  * PaymentLine
  *
  * @ORM\Table()
  * @ORM\Entity
  * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
  */
  class PaymentLine
  {

   /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @JMS\Exclude()
     */
     protected $id;

   /**
     * @var Payment
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Payment", inversedBy="paymentLines")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @JMS\Exclude()
     */
     protected $payment;

   /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="concept", type="string", length=255)
     * @JMS\Groups({"public", "create"})
     */
     protected $concept;

   /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="quantity", type="smallint")
     * @JMS\Groups({"public", "create"})
     */
     protected $quantity;

   /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="unit_price", type="decimal", precision=5, scale=2)
     * @JMS\Groups({"public", "create"})
     */
    protected $unitPrice;
}
```

As you can see this is a OneToMany association, this association is handled by form to validate the data. After the data is validate, I want to store it in the database to process it after, so I use these code lines to do that:

```
 $payment = new Payment();
 $paymentForm = $this->createForm('payment', $payment);

 $paymentForm->handleRequest($request);

 if ($paymentForm->isValid()) {            

    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entityManager->persist($payment);
    $entityManager->flush();
 }
```

This code handle the form that receives all the payment data (payment data and payment lines data) to validate them and store in the database. When I execute this code, I get this error:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'payment_id' cannot be null

Every advice will be welcome and appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I just noticed you have @JMS\Exclude() in $payment. _"This annotation can be defined on a property to indicate that the property should not be serialized/unserialized. Works only in combination with NoneExclusionPolicy."_ dunno if this the reason

Comment: @oskr It's there because when I return this payment through an API, I don't want to return that. Thank you for your notice.

Comment: Sounds similar to this: (take a look at your `public function add paymentLine` in your Payment entity) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725679/symfony2-referencedcolumnname-id-is-null

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Keefe Kwan, I've solved my issue. Like he said on the comment, my issue was the code generated by Doctrine, "addPaymentLine" method to be more specific, this method was as follows:

```
/**
 * Add paymentLines
 *
 * @param PaymentLine $paymentLines
 * @return Payment
 */
public function addPaymentLine(PaymentLine $paymentLines)
{
    $this->paymentLines[] = $paymentLines;

    return $this;
}
```

So I edited it adding this line:

```
$paymentLines->setPayment($this);
```

But just adding that it didn't work, so I took a look to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725679/symfony2-referencedcolumnname-id-is-null), and I didn't have the "by_reference" parameter in the form, so my form was like this:

```
$builder
            ->add('payment_lines', 'collection',
                    [
                'type' => new PaymentLineType(),
                'allow_add' => true
                    ]
            )
```

So adding that parameter my form is now like this:

```
$builder
            ->add('payment_lines', 'collection',
                    [
                'type' => new PaymentLineType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false
                    ]
            )
```

So finally, my problem has been solved. Thank you guys for your help.

Regards

Comment: The `'by_reference' => false` line did it for me, good catch! Without it, in my code it the `addPaymentLine()` setter would never been called.